# convert proc calis SAS to lavaan r package

Tags: r, sas

I am very new to R. I am trying to replicate a SAS proc calis which calculates SEM simultaneous equations using the code:

```
proc calis te data= data ucov AUGMENT outest = estimate outstat=mdl_stat_final2 MAXITER = 10000 tech= QUANEW method=ML print privec;
                lineqs sales = a v1 + b v2 + c v3 + d v4 + e v5+ e1,
                       v2 = f v3 + g v4   + e2,
                       v4 =   i v3 + j v5 + e3;
                STD e1 = Var_e1,
                    e2 = Var_e2,
                    e3 = Var_e3;
                ods output 
                  TotalEffects = total
                  IndirectEffects = indirect
                  TValues = tval
                 ;
        run;
```

I have used the lavaan package for this purpose:

```
require(lavaan)
eqn <- 'Sales ~ a*v1 + b*v2 + C*v3 + d*v4 + e*v5 
          v2 ~ f*v3 + g*v4 
          v4 ~ i*v3 + j*v5 '

fit.eqn <- sem(eqn,data= data)
```

The estimates I get from R are different from the SAS result. Are there additional conditions which need to be applied to get the same result as SAS? Is there any other package which I could use to replicate the SAS code in R?

@thelatemail:  Major differences in estimates are when R gives a positive estimate while the estimate from SAS is negative or vice versa. The estimates from the R and SAS are as follows:

```
Sales ~     Estimate from R Estimate from SAS
    v1 (a)       2.562                         1.094
    v2 (b)       0.127                         0.109
    v3 (C)       0.016                        -0.011
    v4 (d)      -0.242                        -0.260
    v5 (d)       0.428                        -0.053
v2 ~            
    v3 (f)       0.032                         0.071
    v4 (g)      -0.264                         0.816
    v5 (d)  no estimate                0.852
v4 ~            
    v3 (i)       0.021                         0.031
    v5 (j)       0.756                         1.044
```

Comment: How are the results different? Major differences or just minor changes around the edges?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your model syntax might be the reason. Can you specify your model structure? What are lv and ov? Also in R, ~ means do regression on that variable. If you have lv at left side of = sign, you need to use =~ instead of ~.